# How to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$
I've tried to convert to polar coordinates:

I let
$$x=r(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)$$
$$y=r(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)$$
Then,
$$\frac{dx}{d\varphi}=r'(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)+r(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)$$
$$\frac{dy}{d\varphi}=r'(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)+r(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)$$
such that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{r'(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)+r(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)}{r'(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)+r(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)}$$
Substitution into the differential equation yields
$$\frac{r'(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)+r(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)}{r'(\varphi)\cdot\cos(\varphi)+r(\varphi)\cdot\sin(\varphi)}=-\frac{\sin(\varphi)}{r(\varphi)}$$
It does not seem to get any easier now does it.

Comment: Did you know any solution of it?

Comment: Maple returns an implicit solution in terms of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if we consider it as $$x'=\frac{x^2+y^2}{-y}=\dfrac{1}{y}x^2-y,~~(y\neq0)$$ then it can be regarded as a [Riccati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
y y'+\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0\Rightarrow \frac 12u'+ \frac{u}{x^2+u}=0
$$

with $u = y^2$